# How to loop through discriminated union cases and call thier member functions on them?

Tags: f#

The goal is the loop through each descrimintated union cases and print out the description for each case e.g

```
type car = 
| Benz 
| Honda 
    member this.description() = 
        match this with 
        |Benz -> "Benz description"
        |Honda -> "Honda description"
```

The calling code would use `FSharpType.GetUnionCases typeof<Car>` and loop through the union cases.

Is this possible to achieve in F#?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It can be done if you have DU without any data, but then, I wonder, if this is actually the most sensible representation for your domain...

Comment: Essentially I just want each case to have a description but I don't want to make each case of string then have to supply the description on creation. I want them to have static descriptions

Comment: That sounds reasonable - but what is the motivation for trying to enumerate all the cases? Do you need that e.g., for offering the options in some UI?

Comment: Yes that was the goal I ended up just making a list that had each case and called thier description function on them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `FSharpValue.MakeUnion`. This example will return a sequence of tuples with the union type and description:

```
type Car = 
| Benz 
| Honda 
    member this.description() = 
        match this with 
        |Benz -> "Benz description"
        |Honda -> "Honda description"

FSharpType.GetUnionCases typeof<Car>
|> Seq.map (fun uci ->
    let c = FSharpValue.MakeUnion(uci, [||]) :?> Car
    (c, c.description()))
```

Example:

```
val it: seq<car * string> =
  seq [(Benz, "Benz description"); (Honda, "Honda description")]
```